# How to auto fit screen resolution in visual force page?

Tags: visualforce, css

How to auto fit screen resolution in visual force page?

I created a VF page in 1920 * 1080 screen resolution. when I viewed the VF page in 1024 * 768 screen resolution, it is showing the horizontal scroll bar. Can anyone give suggestion how to auto fit screen for all resolutions with browser compatibility?

Comment: I think it is called "Responsive Design" and has nothing to do with Salesforce, but with html/css

Comment: ... and unlike [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) the "Classic" Visualforce CSS was not designed with responsiveness in its feature set.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, if you don't "abuse" any elements, you shouldn't need to be auto-fitting anything. Visualforce does a pretty good job of running in 1024 resolution. For pages that are borderline, try using sidebar="false" to free up the extra space of a sidebar. This is done in several larger pages (e.g. reports, dashboards) in the standard UI.

If that's just not good enough, you'll want to learn "responsive" design. That means it's time to pick up the [Salesforce Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) and start using that. You can use SLDS in Apex Code using [apex:slds](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm). Generally, SLDS will form to all kinds of screen resolutions from phones to Ultra Wide HD without *too* much effort on the developer's part.

Or, you might look in to [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), another popular responsive design system. I prefer to stay within Salesforce, though, so I've been taking the time to learn SLDS, and I really recommend it for future projects.

No matter what you do, however, it's always important to test in 1024 mode. Set up a separate desktop, open the Developer Console of Chrome, and specify a device resolution of 1024. This will force Chrome to resize to the specific size and you'll get a better feel for your code.

Actual specifics of how to fix a given Visualforce will vary depending on the code, but as I said above, it's really about learning the design limits of the various elements, and trying to not cram too much stuff into the horizontal space.